# React Navigation - Custome header on file.js ( this file isn't the file define navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the issue that custom header,

I have 4 file.js (navigation.js , screenA.js, screenB.js, screenC.js),

I define in navigation.js
 - createBottomTabNavigator = {screenA.js , screenB.js}
 - createStackNavigator = {screenC.js , createBottomTabNavigator}

I want to custom [ header, headerLeft , headerRight, headerTitle ] 
on screenA.js, screenB.js, screenC.js. I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make custom headers for each file within NavigationOptions of those files itself.

Code:

class A extends Component {

```
//--->>>Specify Navigation Properties for screen------>>>

static navigationOptions = () => ({        

    headerStyle : { backgroundColor: 'black' },
    headerTitle :<View>
                    <HeaderLogo /> 
                 </View>,
    headerLeft : <TouchableOpacity> 
                    <MenuIcon />
                 </TouchableOpacity>,
    headerRight: <TouchableOpacity> 
                    <ProfileIcon />
                 </TouchableOpacity>,

})
```

//=======Your other Code========//

}